# Detect the end of playback of a MP3 file with DFPlayerMini / DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h library

Tags: esp8266, audio, rtc

For a project I'm doing I've used an ESP8266/12e, a RTC Module DS3231 and a DFplayerMini

Basically it's a caller for birds and it has to play a 12-minute long MP3. The MP3 file should be played for 2 hours at the sunrise and 2 hours before the sunset, so each time it should be played 10 times (*10 × 12 = 120 minutes (2 hours)*)

The code I wrote so far (some parts are omitted for brevity):

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include "DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h"
#include <Wire.h>       
#include <RtcDS3231.h>  

#define DELAY_ONPLAY 1000
#define DELAY_ONPAUSE 20000



// RTC Library (I2C)
RtcDS3231<TwoWire> rtcObject(Wire); 

// MP3 Serial communication
SoftwareSerial mySoftwareSerial(14, 12);
DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer;



// Variables
int volume, mth, day, h, m;

// State of the playback
int playbackCount = 0;
bool isPlaying = false;

RtcDateTime currentTime;

void setup() {

    mySoftwareSerial.begin(9600);
    // Start serial connection
    Serial.begin(115200);  
    // Start I2C
    rtcObject.Begin();    

    if (!myDFPlayer.begin(mySoftwareSerial)) {  
      while(true){
        delay(10);
      }
    }

    /* Get the value of potentiometer in the range of [3..30] and
     * set the volume
     */    
    setVolume();


}



void loop() {

    setVolume();
    currentTime = rtcObject.GetDateTime();    //get the time from the RTC

    mth  = currentTime.Month();
    day  = currentTime.Day();
    h    = currentTime.Hour();
    m    = currentTime.Minute();


    /* The caller is not playing: check if date and time should
     * start the playback
     */
    if (isPlaying == false) {

        if (startSunrise() || startSunset()) {
            isPlaying = true;
        }

        else {
            // Nothing to do for the next 20 seconds
            delay(DELAY_ONPAUSE);
        }
    }

    else {


      // Currently playing
      if (playbackCount < 10) {

          if (/* MP3mini_is_idle */) {

            myDFPlayer.play(1);
            playbackCount = playbackCount + 1;

          }
      }

      else {
        playbackCount = 0;
        isPlaying = false;
        Serial.print("End of playback");
      }

      delay(DELAY_ONPLAY); 

    }
}



void setVolume() {

    // Get the value of potentiometer in the range of [3..30]
    volume = map(analogRead(A0), 0, 1023, 2, 30);
    volume = constrain(volume, 3, 30);
    // Set the player volume 
    myDFPlayer.volume(volume);  
    Serial.println(String(volume));

}



bool startSunrise() {

    /* at the sunrise the call has to be played for 2 hours */

    if (mth == 2) {
        if ((day == 20 && h == 7 && m == 8) ||
            (day == 21 && h == 7 && m == 6) ||
            ...
            (day == 28 && h == 6 && m == 54) ||
            (day == 29 && h == 6 && m == 52)) { return true; }
    }

    if (mth == 3) {
        if ((day == 1  && h == 6 && m >= 49) ||
            (day == 2  && h == 6 && m >= 47) ||
            (day == 3  && h == 6 && m >= 45 ) ||
            (day == 4  && h == 6 && m >= 43) ||
            ...
            (day == 27 && h == 6 && m >= 0) ||
            (day == 28 && h == 5 && m >= 58)) { return true; }
    }

    return false;
}



bool startSunset() {

    /* 2 hours before sunset the call has to be played for 2 hours */

    if (mth == 2) {
        if ((day == 20 && h == 15 && m >= 41) ||
            (day == 21 && h == 15 && m >= 42) ||
            ...
            (day == 28 && h == 15 && m >= 52) ||
            (day == 29 && h == 15 && m >= 54)) { return true; }
    }

    if (mth == 3) {
        if ((day == 1  && h == 15 && m >= 56) ||
            (day == 2  && h == 15 && m >= 58) ||
            (day == 3  && h == 15 && m >= 59) ||
            (day == 4  && h == 16 && m >= 1) ||
            ...
            (day == 27 && h == 16 && m >= 31) ||
            (day == 28 && h == 16 && m >= 33)) { return true; }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The part I'm stuck on is

```
  if (playbackCount < 10) {

      if (/* MP3mini_is_idle */) {

        myDFPlayer.play(1);
        playbackCount = playbackCount + 1;

      }

  }
```

How do I detect in the `if` condition if the MP3 is actually playing before play it again? 
I think a 12-minute `delay()` is not the right approach.

In the image below the DFPlayerMini pinout: I noticed It has a `BUSY` pin  but I haven't found examples so far that uses this pin to detect the playback state.

[image]

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Have you googled for this? I directly found [this site](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/DFPlayer_Mini_SKU_DFR0299). The table under the image, that you have in your question, states, that the BUSY pin is LOW, when the DFPlayer is playing something. Isn't that exactly, what you want?

Comment: Thank you. I'll try as soon as possibile and I'll give you a feedback in a few hours

Comment: Alternatively you could create a new audio file that has the bird song, repeated 10 times, in it. PS if you go with the repeated playback code, I'd have the song repeat till it reaches 120minutes (using millis()), instead of repeating it 10 times. That way if you ever change the sound file, and that file has a different length, you wouldn't have to update the code.

Comment: @chrisl, I've solved checking the busy pin. If you like to put the comment as the answer I would be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1):

As @chrisl alread said, you could use the busy pin. Or a simple serial query

```
myDFPlayer.readState();
```

If the result is something like `DFPlayerPlayFinishe` the actual track is complete.

Comment: I've solved checking the busy pin, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The busy pin, means that the flash memory is being accessed. So its not the same as "track being played".